# Laptop with 3 monitors flickers and moves everything to primary monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop with 3 monitors connected, two are connected via a device and one is plugged directly into the laptop. All with hdmi

I use this set up to connect to a cloud desktop for work

Randomly everything will flicker and everything moves to the primary display, while I'm working.

I've updated all drivers, set the laptop not to go to sleep (I don't do a lot with the laptop screen,  thought it might be trying to sleep)

Could this laptop not be able to handle it?

Laptop

- HP - Spectre 2-in-1 16" 3K+ Touch-Screen Laptop - Intel Evo Platform Core i7 - 16GB Memory - 512GB SSD +32GB Optane - Nocturne Blue
- Model: 16-F0013DX
- SKU: 6480377

Monitors

- Element Electronics - Element 27" IPS LED 1080p Full HD  - Frameless Monitor - Black
- Model:EM2FPAB27BSKU:6483401

Connector for two of the monitors

- USBC-6950UE

Comment: How are the devices connected to power and outlets? Could you have power fluctuations?

Comment: The laptop and one monitor are directly in the wall two monitors are surge protector then into same outlet

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you sometimes have a power problem.
This might be a problem with your house, where for example
some heavy device sometimes turns on and causes electrical
surges or something in your house. A remark below also raises
the possibility of a bad cable/socket connection.

The laptop may not be affected, because it has a battery that
protects in some measure and helps avoid reboot or shutdown.
The monitors are not so lucky,
as they only have a surge protector, so in effect they turn off
for a short while.

The laptop sees that the two monitors have disappeared,
thinks they have been turned off,
so it moves all their windows to the primary display.
When the monitors turn on immediately afterward,
this is too late.

If your house or neighborhood has undependable power,
I would suggest to put your entire installation behind a UPS with
a battery, which would protect all your devices.

Comment: A surge protector [MOV] acts as an 'overflow valve' siphoning excess voltage over to earth. This should never allow the nominal voltage throughput to drop. I'd more suspect a brown-out, or dodgy cable/socket. This makes more sense if three displays suffer the same simultaneous symptom, yet one isn't on the MOV. UPS would definitely make sense, assuming simple connectivity can be ruled out.

Comment: @Tetsujin: You're right - this is a laptop, which I haven't taken into account. Answer modified.

Comment: I will try that. It would make sense as it's very random, might happen once a day or 5. If could be the AC kicking on. I tried booking everything up to another socket first,  same thing

Comment: UPS did not not solve it

Comment: I don't know of anything beside a power cut that can do that. Are the monitors also on the UPS?